# refreshing a page with same tab href selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just want to add a functionality which I found in this jquery website http://jqueryui.com/support/ so when this website is selected and when a specific tab is pressed it opens its contents. but when i refresh it opens the same tab. but the same I am trying to implement in my code. any suggestions to it.

Code :-

```
<div class="coolbar">
    <div class="cool-inner">
        <ul id="mybar" class="nav cool-tabs">
            <li class="Coke">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Coke </a><span class="dashboard-bottom"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="Fanta">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Fanta</a><span class="Pricing-bottom"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="Pepsi">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Pepsi</a><span class="Promotion-bottom"></span>
            </li>
            <li class="Limca">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Limca</a><span class="Product-bottom"></span>                         </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I refresh my page. the tab which I have selected must get reloaded. and no the first tab should get loaded. any suggestions. please help.It has to be done in ajax or javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the url contains the current opened tab. This will enable you to retrieve that data when the browser is refreshed. With that info you can than load the correct tab.

In a Single Page Application (SPA) this is particularly done with the use of route definitions.

Comment: Ohw, is that it? Your looking for a ready-to-go piece of code. Remember, this is not a 'please program a solution for me' forum.

Comment: yes i knew it. the thing is that i have seen many jquery pages which jus works in the way i want only by importing certain .js and css files. with an example or demo is posted it may be easy to understand the concept and implement.

Comment: You can look at the documentation of SPA frameworks (Backbone, Angular, KnockOut): http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

The jQuery Address plugin provides powerful deep linking capabilities and allows the creation of unique virtual addresses that can point to a website section or an application state.

Comment: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/
No need for fiddle. Check out this demo

Comment: i am currently using jquery 1.9.1 version. when i add this address,js version will it affect my functionality of 1.9.1.js?

Comment: it sure not. I am using this with jquery 1.8